# Разница append и insert в ADO Delphi 7

Tags: ado, delphi, база-данных

***Организую добавление записей в таблицу следующим образом:***

В конец таблицы  - методом **Append**:

```
Form2.ADOQuery1.Append;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Номер').AsInteger:= Form2.ADOQuery1.RecordCount+1;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Название книги').AsString:=Edit1.Text;   
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Автор').AsString:=Edit2.Text;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Кол-во страниц').AsInteger:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text);  
Form2.ADOQuery1.Post;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.Refresh;
```

В текущую позицию - методом **Insert**:

```
Form2.ADOQuery1.Insert;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Номер').AsInteger:= Form2.ADOQuery1.RecordCount+1;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Название книги').AsString:=Edit1.Text;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Автор').AsString:=Edit2.Text;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Кол-во страниц').AsInteger:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text);  
Form2.ADOQuery1.Post;  
Form2.ADOQuery1.Refresh;
```

Поля *Номер* и *Кол-во страниц* - числовые, остальные - текстовые. Ключевое поле - *Номер*.

Теперь проблема: Метод *Insert* почему-то добавляет запись в конец таблицы, хотя должен сдвигать записи и вставлять новую в текущую позицию.

Comment: Теперь проблема: Метод Insert почему-то добавляет запись в конец таблицы,
 хотя должен сдвигать записи и вставлять новую в текущую позицию.  - вы ето как себе представляете?

Comment: Вы сами свой код читали?
Где код от **Insert**?

Вам **автоинкриминентные** поля известны?

Что значит добавляет в конец таблицы?
Как вы смотрите порядок в таблице?

В общем хороший учебник по **SQL** Вам в помощь.

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался, вставив один и тот же код сюда дважды. В программе естественно для вставки - Insert, для добавления в конец - Append. Насчет поля-счетчика - пробовал сделать 'Номер' таковым, но мне не нравится, что даже удалив все записи (коих было, например, 9) и вставив новую, номер у нее будет 10. Ввиду неопытности работы с БД в Делфи (ADO в частности), не знаю, как это обойти. Мое задание предполагает использовать в данном случае методы ADO, а не  SQL, так что справочником по SQL, даже хорошим, мне можно разве что подтереть зад, и то, если бумага будет не жесткая.

Comment: Метод Insert выполняет следующие действия:  
 - переводит НД в режим вставки;  
 - сдвигает записи на одну вперед, начиная от текущей;  
 - вставляет на место текущей записи новую пустую запись;  
  
Вячеслав Понамарев "Самоучитель. Базы данных в Delphi 7"

Comment: Ваш метод **.RecordCount+1;** изначально тупиковый вариант.
Так как может множество коллизий, особенно если с базой в один момент времени работает более одного клиента.

В общем работают методы верно метод **Append** открывает таблицу для редактирование, а метод **Insert** вставляет новую строку.
а то что вам кажется в середину или в конец это всего лишь иллюзия.

есть хороший форум SQL.RU вот его почитайте и многое поймете.

Comment: Метод Append ведь добавляет 1 пустую запись в конец таблицы. Но делает он ли это внутри таблицы в самой БД, либо же в абстрактном наборе данных, хранящемся в памяти и доступном через TADOQuery или TDataSet? То же самое хочу узнать и по поводу Insert.